# What are some ways to switch conversation topics?

Tags: synonyms

Currently, when I'm in the middle of a topic and I have something else that I'd like to bring up I'll say

`unrelated, but...` or sometimes `apropos of nothing`

Are there any other good ways to bring in a new topic?

Comment: I dunno. are the other ppl still eagerly engaged in the current topic? if so, maybe there's no good way to try to switch topics

Comment: "By the way..." You could add "Before I forget..." if there is something you want to mention but fear you may lose the opportunity if the conversation goes on to other things.

Comment: There always this: *"Squirrel!*" (A meme referred to in the movie [*Up*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1049413/). It refers to people with short attention spans who are easily distracted by various things in the middle of a sentence of action.)

Comment: “Oh, before I forget ...”

Comment: You are on the wrong site. Please read the label. Try English Language Learners

Answer (score 1):

In a formal conversation I've presented as a rhetorical question, "If I may bring up another matter..." and "If I may ask a question not pertaining to our present subject...". In casual conversations one might use phases such as, "Switching gears..." then bring up the next topic. I've also used, "Changing horses in midstream..." then brought up a new subject.